# building custom dojo

Tags: dojo

I have to build the dojo tool kit for dojo optimisation. I have download the file from 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-custom/index.html#resources
now i have run the instraction as in readme.txt file. now for build time it is showing me this 
"no profile provided"
I have set all sccording to the instraction as in readme.txt file.
and last What is the another path for this
"
`./build.sh     -profileFile=../../test.profile.js action=clean,release releaseName=myRelease`"

command i think its a linux command 
i have change this.
"
`build.bat  -profileFile=../../test.profile.js action=clean,release releaseName=myRelease` "
but it is not finding the test.profile.js and it is saying me that no profile is provided.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306670/adding-dojo-widget-inside-custom-widget/9308000#9308000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for the profile is relative to the build.bat

If the following is the directory structure:

```
js
  dojo
  dijit
  dojox
  util
    buildscripts
      build.bat
  test.profile.js
```

then the path would look like `../../myProfile.js`

Since this is the path that you posted, verify that the profile is where I described above.