# 2 dojo base urls

Tags: dojo, require

I'm using dojo hosted on google's CDN, which means google's cdn is dojo's base url path. But I have files on my server I want to load with dojo.require. how can I do this? currently I'm getting an error that it can't access the file, but that's because it doesn't exist on google's cdn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can config at `data-dojo-config` or in `djConfig`

By setting `baseUrl` and `modulePaths`

This link would be help. http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/cdn/

Comment: @LordZardeck See here for more information about the path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306670/adding-dojo-widget-inside-custom-widget/9308000#9308000 may be help.