# How do I include a template in another template in a Dojo Widget?

Tags: javascript, templates, dojo

I have tried to do this using the following template models:

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="includeHere"</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div>
    ${includeHere}
</div>
```

Then in the class I thought it should be something like:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/myWidget.html",
    "dojo/text!./templates/templateToBeIncluded.html"
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    template,
    templateToBeIncluded
) {
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
            templateString: template,

            buildRendering: function() {
                this.includeHere = templateToBeIncluded;
            },

        });
});
```

I cheked _TemplatedMixin source and tried to change buildRendering function according to the way _TemplatedMixin does it:

```
buildRendering: function() {
    domConstruct.toDom(templateToBeIncluded, this.includeHere);
},
```

But lso couldn't make it work. What is the right way to do this ? I don't want to include HTML in my .js file. I want to have the HTML only in templates.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you need to include a widget inside another widget? Could be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306670/adding-dojo-widget-inside-custom-widget

Comment: Well... I'm still starting in Dojo. Maybe I didn't get the "Dojo way" of doing things. But actually the idea was I didn't need a widget inside the widget... I only needed a subtemplate. But on second thought, it's almost the same thing isn't it ? well... do you think I should convert the sub-templates to widgets ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. First when I simply introduce `this.inherited(arguments);` in the buildRendering method, it worked, but the HTML didn't render. It apear in the page as raw HTML. So I tried to change the variable in the template to ${!includeHere). As soon as I did this the HTML rendered correctly.

But it remained the problem that substitution variables in the sub-template, weren't rendered, so I changed the buildRendering method to this:

```
buildRendering: function() {
    this.includeHere = string.substitute(templateToBeIncluded, this, (v) => v);
    this.inherited(arguments);
},
```

And it all worked fine.